# Unable to perform calculations because Stockhistory takes too long to autopopulate

Tags: excel, vba, populate

Happy Friday!

I've written code that inserts the stockhistory function into a cell to pull the closing prices for a specific period of time. Following the code that performs this action, I have more code (underneath the comment "Calculate Interval Returns") that calculates the return for each period from the closing prices that was pulled using the stockhistory function.

Unfortunately, the stockhistory function takes too long for the data to populate and so the return calculations don't appear. Is there a way to get around this either by forcing the macro to wait until the data has populated, or some other method? Here is my code:

```
Sub Insert_Ticker()

Dim wsList, wsData As Worksheet
Dim Ticker, Return_Interval, x As String
Dim i, y, Interval_Code, Interval_Converter, Return_Years, Last_Column, Last_Row As Integer
Dim Security_Table As ListObject
Dim New_Table_Row As ListRow

Set wsList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Securities_List")
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Securities_Data")
Set Security_Table = wsList.ListObjects("Security_Table")

'Assign variable to info

Sheet1.Activate

Ticker = wsList.range("C2")
Return_Interval = wsList.range("C3")
Return_Years = wsList.range("C4")

'Ensure 3 input fields contain info

If Ticker = "" Or Return_Interval = "" Or Return_Years = "" Then
    If Ticker = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please Enter Ticker Symbol")
        range("C2").Activate
    ElseIf Return_Interval = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please Enter Return Interval")
        range("C3").Activate
    ElseIf Return_Years = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please Enter Years")
        range("C4").Activate
    End If
    Exit Sub
End If

'Ensure ticker isn't already in table

Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Last_Row
    If Cells(i, 6) = Ticker Then
        MsgBox ("Security Already Exists")
        wsList.ListObjects("Security_Table").ListRows(i - 2).range.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

'If ticker isn't already in table, add ticker

Set New_Table_Row = Security_Table.ListRows.Add
Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
range("E" & Last_Row).Value = Ticker
range("E" & Last_Row).ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:="en-US"

'Prepare info for formula to return metrics

Interval_Converter = Return_Years * 365

Select Case Return_Interval
    Case "Daily"
        Interval_Code = 0
    Case "Weekly"
        Interval_Code = 1
    Case "Monthly"
        Interval_Code = 2
End Select

Sheet2.Activate

'Pull Historical Closing Prices for Ticker

Last_Column = wsData.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
wsData.Cells(1, Last_Column) = Ticker
wsData.Cells(2, Last_Column).Activate
'Ticker = Chr(34) & Ticker & Chr(34)
'MsgBox (Ticker)
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=STOCKHISTORY(" & Chr(34) & Ticker & Chr(34) & ",TODAY()-" & Interval_Converter & ", TODAY()," & Interval_Code & ")"
wsData.Cells(2, Last_Column + 2) = "Periodic Return"

'Calculate Interval Returns

Last_Column = wsData.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Last_Row = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, Last_Column - 1).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox (Last_Row & ", " & Last_Column)

For i = 4 To Last_Row
    Cells(i, Last_Column) = (Cells(i, Last_Column - 1) - Cells(i - 1, Last_Column - 1)) / Cells(i, Last_Column - 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: DoEvents might work.

Comment: @braX this user submitted 2 questions very closely together in time.  It seems like you meant to respond to their other question.

Comment: How about ActiveCell.Calculate right after putting in the StockHistory function?